# Juspay integration not working - I get authorization or bad origin errors

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm using [Juspay](https://www.juspay.in/) for my app. I created an account in sandbox mode from [here](https://sandbox.juspay.in/)

Get the API key from settings.

I'm creating an order as in [doc](https://www.juspay.in/docs/api/ec/#create-order).

It's giving response as

```
stdClass Object ( [error_code] => bad_origin [error_message] => Bad Origin. Permission denied. [juspay_request_id] => b0aea3ab-6939-460b-971e-070d194f2fb4 )
```

What's the api url for sandbox mode? If I'm using `https://api.juspay.in/order/create` I get an authorization error.

If I try with `https://sandbox.juspay.in/order/create` I get a bad origin error.

Comment: do you have openssl

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap yes

Comment: did you whitelisted your ip or url?

Comment: Thx, Fixed the prob. Whitelisted one ip address and testing in another ip.